# Get currently called function to write anonymous recursive function

Tags: r

How can I get the current function within a function for recursive applying? Here is a trivial example:

```
myfun <- function(x) {
  if(is.list(x)){
    lapply(x, myfun)
  } else {
    length(x)
  }
}
```

I would like to make it anonymous instead, however I don't know how to tell `lapply` to use the current function when it has no name. I tried `Recall` but that doesn't work:

```
(function(x) {
  if(is.list(x)){
    lapply(x, Recall)
  } else {
    length(x)
  }
})(cars)
```

Also `match.call()[[1]]` doesn't help for anonymous functions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is `sys.function(0)` , for example to compute the square of a list recursively :

```
(function(x) {
  if(length(x)>2){
    lapply(x,sys.function(0))
  } else {
    x^2
  }
})(list(1,2,3))

 [[1]]
[1] 1

[[2]]
[1] 4

[[3]]
[1] 9
```

Comment: Good, but why do you `lapply()` this to  `x[-1]` rather than `x`?

Comment: @JoshO'Brien good catch. I tested it with something like `sys.function(0)(x[-1])` without `lapply`...

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is, I think, [`sys.function`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/sys.parent.html):

```
> (function() print(sys.function(1)))()
function() print(sys.function(1))
```

[`Recall`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Recall.html) actually says:

> [`local`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/eval.html) for another way to write anonymous recursive functions.

The idea is that you define the name locally:

```
local(myfun <- function(...) { ... myfun(...) ... })
```

and it is not defined outside.